# Print the sum of even digits of a number in Pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

[image]

I cant seem to resolve this issue

Comment: Is the use of explicit cursors part of your assignment? Didn't they teach you implicit cursors (which are much, much easier to use)? This is aside from the errors etc. in your current attempt.

Answer (score 0):

As of the error itself, it is because you're trying to put the whole **row** (`temp`, which is declared as a cursor variable - `c_nm%rowtype`) into an integer variable (`i`). It won't work, although `temp` actually contains only one column - `num`.

So, line #15 on your screenshot:

```
No : i := temp;
Yes: i := temp.num;
```

Once you fix it, your code *works* but - unfortunately, produces wrong result. In input number 121974553, even digits are 2, 9, 4 and 5 whose sum equals 20, not 6 (as your result suggests):

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  2    ad int := 0;
  3    i int;
  4    b int;
  5    cursor c_nm is select * From numb;
  6    temp c_nm%rowtype;
  7  begin
  8    open c_nm;
  9    loop
 10      fetch c_nm into temp;
 11      exit when c_nm%notfound;
 12      i := temp.num;                  --> this
 13
 14      while i > 0 loop
 15        b := mod(i, 10);
 16        if mod(b, 2) = 0 then
 17           ad := b + ad;
 18        end if;
 19        i := trunc(i/10);
 20      end loop;
 21    end loop;
 22    dbms_output.put_line('ad = ' ||ad);
 23    close c_nm;
 24  end;
 25  /
ad = 6

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

A simpler option might be this: split number into digits (each in its separate row) so that you could apply `SUM` function to its even digits:

```
SQL> select * from numb;

       NUM
----------
 121974553     --> sum of even digits = 2 + 9 + 4 + 5 = 20
 253412648     -->                    = 5 + 4 + 2 + 4 = 15

SQL> with
  2  split as
  3    -- split number into rows
  4    (select num,
  5            substr(num, column_value, 1) digit,
  6            case when mod(column_value, 2) = 0 then 'Y'
  7                 else 'N'
  8            end cb_odd_even
  9     from numb cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 10                                              connect by level <= length(num)
 11                                             ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 12    )
 13  -- final result: summary of digits in even rows
 14  select num,
 15         sum(digit)
 16  from split
 17  where cb_odd_even = 'Y'
 18  group by num;

       NUM SUM(DIGIT)
---------- ----------
 253412648         15
 121974553         20

SQL>
```

---

If it *must* be PL/SQL, slightly rewrite it as

```
SQL> declare
  2    result number;
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select num from numb) loop
  5      with
  6      split as
  7        -- split number into rows
  8        (select substr(cur_r.num, level, 1) digit,
  9                case when mod(level, 2) = 0 then 'Y'
 10                     else 'N'
 11                end cb_odd_even
 12         from dual
 13         connect by level <= length(cur_r.num)
 14        )
 15      -- final result: summary of digits in even rows
 16      select sum(digit)
 17      into result
 18      from split
 19      where cb_odd_even = 'Y';
 20
 21      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.num || ' --> ' || result);
 22    end loop;
 23  end;
 24  /
121974553 --> 20
253412648 --> 15

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I think you are confusing "even digits" with "digits of even order". In the OP's sample number, the digits 2 and 4 are even; all the other digits are odd. In the number 13559, all digits are odd. And, I assume it **must** be PL/SQL; this looks very much like homework, and I doubt the OP would have asked for PL/SQL by name if that wasn't part of the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. A few things of note: first, you can use an implicit cursor (the `for rec in (select ...) loop` construct). You don't need to declare the data type of `rec`, you don't need to open the cursor - and then remember to close it when you are finished - etc. Implicit cursors are a great convenience, best to learn about it as early as possible. Second, note that `rec` (in my notation) is just a pointer; to access the value from it, you must reference the table column (as in, `rec.num`) - Littlefoot has already shown that in his reply. Third, a logic mistake in your attempt: if the table has more than one row, you must initialize `ad` to 0 for each new value - you can't just initialize it to 0 once, at the beginning of the program.

So, with all that said - here is some sample data, then the procedure and its output.

```
create table numb (num int);

insert into numb values(121975443);
insert into numb values(100030000);
insert into numb values(null);
insert into numb values(113313311);
insert into numb values(2020);

commit;
```

. . . . .

```
declare
  ad int;
  i  int;
begin
  for rec in (select num from numb) loop
    ad := 0;
    i  := rec.num;
    while i > 0 loop
      if mod(i, 2) = 0 then
        ad := ad + mod(i, 10);
      end if;
      i := trunc(i/10);
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line('num: ' || nvl(to_char(rec.num), 'null') || 
                                    '  sum of even digits: ' || ad);
  end loop;
end;
/

num: 121975443  sum of even digits: 10
num: 100030000  sum of even digits: 0
num: null  sum of even digits: 0
num: 113313311  sum of even digits: 0
num: 2020  sum of even digits: 4


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```